# How can I translate the names of days and months in Tkcalendar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

I want to translate calendar to another language.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *

wT = Tk()
wT.geometry("400x600")
wT.title("Takvim")
wT.iconbitmap("images/cal.ico")
wT["bg"] = "Grey"

cal = Calendar(wT, selectmode= "day")
cal.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=75, pady=25)
wT.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to tkcalendar's [documentation](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html) there is a "locale" option:

> locale : str 
> locale to use, e.g. ‘en_US’

tkcalendar uses [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/index.html) module to translate the week days and months. I don't know which language you want to use but it is most likely available. For instance, to get the calendar in Swedish:

```
cal = Calendar(wT, locale='sv_se', selectmode= "day")
```